# Mongo $and is slow with indexes

Tags: javascript, mongodb, indexing

I'm wondering if my indexes are wrong here.

I have about 100k rows, will soon be 500k.

This is the query

```
db.article_raw.find({
   $and : [
     {'media.images.0.url': {$exists:true}},
     {'media.images.0.width': {$exists:true}}
   ]
});
```

Here are my indexes for that

```
{
    "media.images.url" : 1
}
```

and

```
{
    "media.images.width" : 1
}
```

The data is something like

```
{
    media: {
       images: [{
           url: "",
           width : ##
      },{
          url: "",
          width: ##
      }]
   }
}
```

This query is taking 3-4 seconds to run. and only .38 when I don't include it. Is $and really that slow or are my indexes messed up?

Comment: use .explain to see if your indexes are been used correctly

Comment: I tried using explain, but I can't figure out how to tell if the indexes are being used correctly.

Comment: http://cl.ly/image/3G360V043g0h

Comment: [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31327473/edit) your question with the `explain` output

Comment: First look at the cursor type. "BasicCursor" is a warning sign: it means MongoDB had to do a full collection scan

Comment: I've since changed this to look at a property on the root object, that is indexed. That is much faster of course.